# DISPLAY environment variable is always 0

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, environment-variables

I have two monitors attached to the same desktop computer. However, when I do `echo $DISPLAY`, it prints `:0.0` on both screens. Shouldn't `echo $DIPLAY` print `:0.1` from one of the screens?

Comment: "Although the screen number is used to select among multiple physical screen that are managed by the same X server, it is rarely set to anything other than "0" nowadays." https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables. For a full answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-display-environment-variable